# Routing Symfony 2 404 profiler debug toolbar

Tags: debugging, toolbar, symfony, apache2.4

In a fresh installation of Symfony 3, the debug toolbar not showing, when I have the apache 2.4.7 configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@enterprise.cl
    ServerName dev.enterprise.cl
    #ServerAlias www.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/gestion/web
    DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/html/gestion>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

If I change the configuration file to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin info@enterprise.cl
    ServerName dev.enterprise.cl
    # ServerAlias www.domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/gestion/web
    # DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/html/gestion>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

And access: http://dev.enterprise.cl/app_dev.php, all going ok.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web directory (in apache config) should be:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/gestion/web>
```

Presuming that 'gestion' is you Symfony3 (is it Symfony3?) folder...

A quick verify (the way it is now) is try:
http://dev.enterprise.cl/web/app_dev.php

By the way, are you using a web browser on the same host? If not you'll need to edit the `app_dev.php` file like so:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], ['192.168.40.208', '192.168.255.99',
            '127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1']) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
```

Where that ['REMOTE_ADDR'] contains the IP of your host; by default it's just localhost (127.0.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot, the solution is uncomment the directive Directory:

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin info@enterprise.cl
        ServerName dev.enterprise.cl
        # ServerAlias www.domain.tld
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/gestion/web
        # DirectoryIndex app_dev.php

        # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
        # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeScript assets
        <Directory /var/www/html/gestion>
            Options FollowSymlinks
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/project_error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/project_access.log combined
  </VirtualHost>
```

Alvin, yes I have configure app_dev, to access remotaly, thanks